# Ubuntu 12.04 Suspend not working FIX

Tags: 12.04, suspend, standby

04 LTS users! If any of you are experiencing the same trouble as I did with the suspend more where the screen stays black after you turn your laptop back on please refer to my fix the last comment that I have posted on this forum:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/989674?comments=all

P.S. Only use the script as a fix if your machine turns back on from suspend and the screen is lit but remains black. This fix should get your GUI and lock screen back. :-)

Comment: I don't see the question here. Make sure to read the FAQ section before posting your question: http://askubuntu.com/faq

Comment: i have same problem.